# Jenkins execute script in background

Tags: jenkins, vagrant

I´m using Vagrant in my local machine with a Python script to start Windows VM with GUI, and it works very well, but I had an idea to automatice this process, running this script with Jenkins, the Windows VM start very well in background but  the process can´t start the GUI.

Any idea???

Thanks.

Comment: do you see the GUI if you start virtual box ? the VM is running in GUI mode no ?

Comment: Vagrant run this vm in gui mode. If I start virtual box I can see the vw but is off and cant start it because other process in background is using it.